# Create launcher shortcut for RDesktop

Tags: unity, command-line, launcher, shortcuts

I am trying to create a 'shortcut' that I can pin to my launcher in Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS that will launch an RDesktop session.

It works fine from the command line thus:

```
rdesktop -u UserName -d Domain -g 1024x720 -a 16 ServerName
```

I found something close in [Terminal command script launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248787/terminal-command-script-launcher), but it does not quite work.

I made the desktop file that contains this (made it executable etc as per the link above):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=RDP-ServerName
Comment=Open an RDP session to ServerName
Exec=rdesktop -u UserName -d Domain -g 1024x720 -a 16 ServerName
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

I figured if I could get it to work from the desktop, then I could somehow pin it to the launcher afterwards?

However,  when I run it from the desktop, nothing seems to happen.  I tried choosing the 'terminal' option, and also the 'run' option, but neither seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar issue with xfreerdp client. Passing parameters from the command line using the terminal works, but could not make it work at first using a desktop launcher (shorcut, in Windows terminology). The solution was to create a script to call the client:

~/bin/RDPWindows.sh:

```
xfreerdp /d: /u:username /p:password /v:10.10.10.10 /size:100% /dynamic-resolution
```

Then, creating a launcher pointing to the script works just fine.

Comment: Good solution - I should have thought of that!  Alan.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy your `*.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications`.

Or use `alacarte` application for this.

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Answer (score -1):

For the Exec= line Try `/usr/bin/rdesktop` as the command to execute. That worked for me when creating a shortcut on my desktop.

Comment: This doesn't create a shortcut.